# Heroku nodejs build failing: "Invalid semver requirement"

Tags: heroku

I'm having a heap of trouble deploying my nodejs app to heroku. While it works perfectly for an initial build (to an empty application in heroku) any subsequent updates that I push fail.

I have defined the node version as "8.9.x", but if I define the exact version number of the latest version, it still fails - saying that "8.9.4" is not a valid semantic version.

If I take the engines section out of my package.json entirely, it tries to resolve "8.x" and then says that "8.x" isn't a valid semantic version!

Is there anything else that I could stuff up in my package.json to cause this? Or can anything outside the package.json be causing this?

Here's the output when pushing to the heroku git repo:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Deleting 2 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.9.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.6.x
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.9.x...
remote:        Error: Invalid semantic version "8.9.x"
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:  !     Invalid semver requirement
remote:
remote:        Node, Yarn, and npm adhere to semver, the semantic versioning convention
remote:        popularized by GitHub.
remote:
remote:        http://semver.org/
remote:
remote:        However you have specified a version requirement that is not a valid
remote:        semantic version.
remote:
remote:        https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-an-invalid-semver-requirement
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to [app name].
remote:
```

And here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "[REDACTED]",
    "version": "3.4.4",
    "description": "[REDACTED]",
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
      "node": "8.9.x",
      "npm": "5.6.x"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "test": "index.js",
      "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+https://[REDACTED]"
    },
    "author": "jasonalex",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE",
    "bugs": {
      "url": "https://[REDACTED]"
    },
    "homepage": "https://[REDACTED]",
    "dependencies": {
      "@google-cloud/logging-winston": "^0.7.0",
      "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.2",
      "@google-cloud/trace-agent": "^2.4.1",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
      "cors": "^2.8.4",
      "cron": "^1.3.0",
      "express": "^4.16.2",
      "filereader": "^0.10.3",
      "firebase-admin": "^5.8.1",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
      "lodash": "^4.17.4",
      "mailgun-js": "^0.14.2",
      "moment": "^2.20.1",
      "multer": "^1.3.0",
      "pdfkit": "^0.8.3",
      "pdfmake": "github:bpampuch/pdfmake",
      "twilio": "^3.11.1",
      "websocket-driver": ">=0.5.1",
      "winston": "^2.4.0",
      "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
      "eslint": "^4.16.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
      "localtunnel": "^1.8.3"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay well I feel a bit silly now - in my case i had added a config var in my heroku settings called 'platform' which was interfering with the official nodejs buildpack.

Removing/renaming this variable has cleared the problem right up.